# Split multiple words into different variables

Tags: php, sql

I fetch skills list from database like-> skill 1, skill 2, skill 3

How could I keep these 3 word into different variable and show them like this

```
 <li> skill 1</li>
 <li> skill 2</li>
 <li> skill 3 </li>
```

Is there any way to do this? I dont want to store this skill 1, skill 2 and skill 3 into different database row

Comment: use php `foreach()` loop to display

Comment: 1 variable, multiple values == `array()`

Answer (score 0):

i.e :

```
<?php
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
    ?>
        <li><?php echo $result["your_value"]?></li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$data = "skill 1, skill 2, skill 3";

echo  "<li>" . str_replace(", ", "</li><li>", $data) . "</li>";
```